# Making a single page website look like infinite scrolling and have objects load in different ways

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have been looking for some pugins og ideas about how to make something with an effect [similar to this](http://demo.spnoy.com/nivan/)

It seems like the whole page is preloaded so only perceived infinite scrolling and the text just appears when in the viewport. Also loading the elements in all these different ways I would like to do, but cannot find anything that can help me.

Comment: I'm sorry if people are downvoting me for missing some code, but basically what I have been looking at so far i the lazy load plugin - my problem with this plugin, however, is that it only seems to work on images - I also want text to appear this way. Sorry for lack of code, but but it is because I am simply so lost for ideas right now.

Comment: read my below comment.. basically dont worry about lazy loading. Just use css transitions to bring the elements into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at jQuery [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).  They probably just use css transitions to transition in elements as you hit certain waypoints.

**EDIT**
and by the way.. people are probably down voting you because you are supposed to at least provide what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that. Tried lazy load so far but only seemed to work with images.

Comment: you dont need to lazy load or anything like that.. just have the original css on the elements when loaded to have them off the screen or faded out.  Then as they hit the waypoints apply a css transition to fade them in and positioned into the view.